# SQLite how to query a string value and return a value in a different column

Tags: android, sqlite

DB name is Phone_Positions.
The table name is Positions.

Below is an example of how the DB table is set up

```
id  |  directions | timestamp

0   | left        |00-00-00 00:00:00

1   | right       |00-00-00 00:00:00

2   | back        |00-00-00 00:00:00

3   | left        |00-00-00 00:00:00

4   | left        |00-00-00 00:00:00
```

I want to write a query that selects all the rows that have the value of  'left' and returns the timestamp.

this is the closes I've  to figuring this out:

```
String selectQuery =  "SELECT * FROM Positions WHERE timestamp  = 'left'";
```

This query doesn't work and I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String selectQuery =  "SELECT timestamp FROM Positions WHERE directions  = 'left'";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT timestamp FROM Phone_Positions WHERE directions = 'left'
```

This will return only the timestamp column which is more efficient than using SELECT * if that's all you want.  The other change is that your Where statement should reference the column that contains the conditional data, not the data that you want to return.